# Reverse linkedlist and writing into a file: Java

Tags: java, linked-list, objectoutputstream, bufferedinputstream

I'm writing code to read a text file, convert it into a LinkedList, and write into another text file in reverse order.

The problem I'm facing is that after converting the text file, I couldn't reverse my list. While writing I'm also facing problems. Here is my code, followed by its output...

```
package Collections;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Store implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter the File Name:");
        String fname1 = br1.readLine();
        FileInputStream fr1 = null;

        // Reading the file

        try {
            fr1 = new FileInputStream(fname1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
            return;
        }
        BufferedInputStream bin1 = new BufferedInputStream(fr1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bin1));
        LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();
        FileOutputStream fout1 = new FileOutputStream("ReverseOrder.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout1);

        // Converting the file into Linked List

        String theWord;
        while (true) {
            theWord = br.readLine();
            if (theWord != null && theWord.length() > 1)
                words.add(theWord);
            if (theWord == null)
                break;
        }
        String[] data = new String[words.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {

            data[i] = words.get(i);

        }
        System.out.println("Words:" + words);

        // Reversing the LInkedList... Here I don't know why
        // Collections.reverse(words) isn't working. I coudn't reverse my list

            Collections.reverse(words);

        System.out.println("Words:" + words);

        // Writing into a file....but here it is not printing in reverse order.
        // In fact if I tried to print in Regular order but it's printing with
        // extra characters

        oos.writeObject(words);
        oos.close();
        bin1.close();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Enter the File Name:replace.txt
Words:[Suresh is a good boy and He completed his graduation from IIT Guwahati in 2013 But he is a great man ]
Words:[Suresh is a good boy and He completed his graduation from IIT Guwahati in 2013 But he is a great man ]
```

The Output printed in the file is :

¬í sr java.util.LinkedList)S]J`ˆ"  xpw   t eSuresh is a good boy and He completed his graduation from IIT Guwahati in 2013 But he is a great man xq ~

Comment: Can you provide the content of your input file please?

Comment: Suresh is a good boy and He completed his graduation from IIT Guwahati in 2013 But he is a great man.......this is the content of my input file

Comment: Is it all written in one line?

Comment: yes...it is written in notepad.....not only this program....the other programs which i have written to text file(sending objects into text file) are showing some ASCII code(unwanted Characters).....and will u plz help me with reversing also....?

Comment: You aren't reversing words but lines try to write each word in a new line and check if that works

Comment: I want to reverse the lines only not the words.....its working as u said "to write each word in a new line" but What about if my file contains paragraph....

Comment: I can't follow you now, so reversing lines works as you expected, than why are you confused that you get the same input as output if you have only one line? That should be the expected behaviour. Also I can't follow you and your paragraph question. Maybe you can edit the question and clarify what exactly you want the program to do for what input file you expect which output.

Comment: The line I provided is the input file...I want my program to print the line in reverse order i.e,. if my line contains Suresh is a good  boy....the output must be boy good a is Suresh.....this output must be  in Linkedlist and have to be printed in another text file.....got it ...?

Comment: Yes, so you want to reverse the order of the words as well as the order of the lines, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are running `Collections.reverse(words);` within the loop. You only need to run it once and skip the loop with adding your own words again. Instead of this:

```
    for (int i = words.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {

        words.add(words.get(i));
        Collections.reverse(words);
    }
```

run only this:

```
Collections.reverse(words);
```

Comment: can you share the new code you have now? (update the question)

Comment: Yeah,I have updated the code but output is same......in the new code I have used oos.writeObject(words) before Collections.reverse(words) but  the objects that are printing into the file are ASCII Code or somthing....see in the output

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong:

```
for (int i = words.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    words.add(words.get(i));
    Collections.reverse(words);
}
```

Why are you doing it in a loop? If `Collections.reverse()` reverses the list, all you need to do is

```
Collections.reverse(words);
```

And you should be done?

Let me know if I'm missing something here

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a LinkedList iterate through the LinkedList pushing the elements onto a Stack until the head of the LinkedList is null. Then pop from the stack adding each element back to your linkedList until the stack is empty.